# How can I change a ZFS mountpoint from legacy to be handled by ZFS

Tags: linux, mount, boot, zfs

Currently using ZFS on ArchLinux.  I have two datasets that I originally setup with legacy mountpoints:

```
# zfs get mountpoint tank/data/home
NAME            PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
tank/data/home  mountpoint  legacy      local
# zfs get mountpoint tank/data/home/kevdog
NAME                   PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
tank/data/home/kevdog  mountpoint  legacy      local
```

I have corresponding entries within /etc/fstab for these mountpoints

I'd like to change these mounts to be handled by zfs rather than mount

I logged in as root, and then did the following:

```
umount /home/kevdog
umount /home
zfs set mountpoint=/home tank/data/home
zfs set mountpoint=/home/kevdog tank/data/home/kevdog
```

I went ahead and commented out the corresponding fstab entries for these mounts

At this point I rebooted system however ran into a problem,
the dataset tank/data/home/kevdog was mounted at /home/kevdog, however the directory was totally empty.  After undoing what I just described above (setting legacy for management of these datasets) the /home/kevdog directory was no longer empty.

Just curious to know why the process didn't work.  Did I have to export/import pool again to make this work?  Did I forget to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

> (…) however the directory was totally empty.

At this point you have to check if the dataset was mounted. Did the system warns you about a *non empty mountpoint*?

> Did I have to export/import pool again to make this work?

Probably, your description looks un-clear for me.

---

Here is the way I move legacy to ZFS mountpoints, even `/` and `/boot`:

1. boot on another disk/system supporting ZFS
2. export *legacy* pool
3. import it again without mounting it
4. set mountpoints, starting by parents mount points
5. remove `fstab` entries
6. export pool
7. reboot

See [my personal notes](https://free_zed.gitlab.io/articles/2022/12/unset-zfs-legacy-mountpoint-proxmox-ovh-installation/en/) related to Proxmox installation about that.